# div loses its full height if another div has a margin

Tags: html, css

I need all divs to be 100% document height. It works till some of them has a top margin. In this case remaining divs loses its full height.

How can I stretch all div's height to full document height, regardless of margin of any of them?

```css
* {
  .margin: 0;
}
html {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  max-width: 1366px;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}
#divleft {
  float: left;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}
#divmiddle {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}
#divright {
  float: right;
  background: green;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='divleft'>left</div>
<div id='divmiddle'>middle</div>
<div id='divright'>right</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/um1o4xm7/)

Comment: Then remove the margin property. Simple

Comment: @SankarRaj, I need that margin.

Comment: @bonaca Do you know about `calc()` function?

Comment: @SauravRastogi I know but height of some div is dinamically changed, according to its content. There is nothing to calc() in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need `height: 100%` for your divs to be full height. You can achieve this layout, making the divs fully dynamic, with CSS flexbox.

All you need is `display: flex` on the container.

You can get rid of all float rules and don't need to use `calc()`.

```css
html {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex; /* NEW */
  max-width: 1366px;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}
#divleft {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 40%;
}
#divmiddle {
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 40%;
  background: lightgreen;
}
#divright {
  width: 20%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='divleft'>left</div>
<div id='divmiddle'>middle</div>
<div id='divright'>right</div>
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/um1o4xm7/1/)

An initial setting of a flex container is `align-items: stretch`. This means that child elements of the container (aka "flex items"), will consume the free space in the *cross-axis*, which in this case is vertical / height.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `calc()` function, like:

```
#divmiddle{
  margin-top: 25px;
  height: calc(100% - 25px);
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below (*let me know if this works for you*):

```css
html{
  background:red;
  height:100%;
}
body{
  max-width:1366px;
  background:blue;
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#divleft{
  float:left;
  background:lightblue;
  width:40%;
  height:100%;
}
#divmiddle{
  float:left;
  margin-top:25px;
  background:lightgreen;
  width:40%;
  height:calc(100% - 25px);
}
#divright{
  float:right;
  background:green;
  width:20%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='divleft'>left</div>
  <div id='divmiddle'>middle</div>
  <div id='divright'>right</div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: height of some div is dinamically changed, according to its content. There is nothing to calc() in advance.

Comment: @bonaca But this will make your height always `100%`, just that your `margin-top` value is subtracted from the total height. This is independent of the content inside your divs, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove margin property from middle div..

```
#divmiddle{
  float:left;
  background:lightgreen;
  width:40%;
 height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Ok then you can define middle div margin as margin-top: auto;

Answer (score 0):

You can simply deduct the margin percentage from the height.  Instead of `height: 100%`, use something like `width: 98%; height: 98%; margin: 1%;` or `width: 23%; height: 23%; margin: 1%;`, etc.